# convert individual response data-frame into team-level data-frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data-frames:

```
> team_1_A
  MemberA Q1 Q2
1      C  2  3
2      B  3  4
> team_1_B
  MemberB Q1 Q2
1      A  5  4
2      C  5  2
> team_1_C
  MemberC Q1 Q2
1      A  2  5
2      B  5  5
```

These data-frames correspond to individual responses regarding their perceptions of team members.  For example, the first data-frame is how team member A (in team 1) perceives team members B and C for questions 1 and 2 (Q1 and Q2). My goal is to automate a process that converts these data-frames from individual responses to team-level data-frames for each question, so that what would be obtained for these data-frames would be:

```
> T1Q1
  X A B C
1 A 0 3 2
2 B 5 0 5
3 C 2 5 0
> T1Q2
  X A B C
1 A 0 3 2
2 B 5 0 5
3 C 2 5 0
```

Thus, 0s appear along the diagonal, and row by row is what each member said about the other for a given question.  For example, in `T1Q1` in row1 we see A's perceptions of B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reshape2` package will make your life easy for this task:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(reshape2)

team_1_A <- data.frame(MemberA=c('C', 'B'), Q1=c(2,3), Q2=c(3,4))
team_1_B <- data.frame(MemberB=c('A', 'C'), Q1=c(5,5), Q2=c(4,2))
team_1_C <- data.frame(MemberC=c('A', 'B'), Q1=c(2,5), Q2=c(5,5))

# store data frames in a list
members <- list(team_1_A, team_1_B, team_1_C)

# format rows/columns
formatted <- lapply(members, function(m){
    m$Respondent <- gsub('Member', '', names(m)[1])
    names(m)[1] <- 'TeamMate'
    return(m)
})
formatted <- do.call('rbind', formatted)

# separate questions into different data frames
questionList <- lapply(c(1,2), function(q) formatted[,c('Respondent', 'TeamMate', paste0('Q',q))])

# reshape, ensure order is correct
questionList <- lapply(questionList, function(q) {
    q <- dcast(q, Respondent ~ TeamMate)
    q <- q[,c('Respondent', 'A', 'B', 'C')]
    return(q)
})
names(questionList) <- c('T1Q1', 'T1Q2')

# replace NA with 0
# etc...
questionList
$T1Q1
  Respondent  A  B  C
1          A NA  3  2
2          B  5 NA  5
3          C  2  5 NA

$T1Q2
  Respondent  A  B  C
1          A NA  4  3
2          B  4 NA  2
3          C  5  5 NA
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it is not dynamic, as I need a solution that works for any number of respondents and questions, where I do not have to specify respondent and question information.

Comment: You're right that this may not be the best solution, but you could generalize my code above by altering two lines: `members <- list(team_1_A, team_1_B, team_1_C)` and `questionList <- lapply(c(1,2)`. It shouldn't be hard to make those two parts dynamic to whatever number of data frames and questions you have...

Comment: Any specific ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It depends on how the data frames will be named and exactly what you want, but an example for assembling the list `members` might be to grep all data frames with `team_` in the name: `dfNames <- ls()[grepl('team_',ls())]` and then assemble them in a list:`members <- lapply(dfNames, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`. For the `lapply` statement to create `questionList`, just put `seq(nQuestions)` in place of `c(1,2)` (provided that you know the number of questions).

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, I am accepting the answer because you have definitely gone above and beyond and have also proposed a nice solution, but the data frames are CSV files. So what my ultimate goal is to apply this to all the CSV files then write the obtained data-frames as new CSV files with the corresponding names.

Comment: You didn't mention that in the original question.